# VBS: How to use %PROGRAMFILES% in objFSO.CopyFile?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to copy a file with the objFSO.CopyFile command in vbs. The problem is, I can not use hard coded paths in my company so I was trying to use a variable. This is the code, when i use `C:\Program Files\` instead of `%PROGRAMFILES%` it works.

```
Option Explicit

dim strFileToCopy
dim strFolder
dim objFSO
dim objWShell

set objFso=createObject("scripting.fileSystemObject")
set objWShell=wScript.createObject("WScript.Shell")

strFileToCopy = "%PROGRAMFILES%\mainfolder\subfolder\netcfg.ini"
strFolder = "%PROGRAMFILES%\othermainfolder\"

Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
  objFSO.CopyFile strFileToCopy, strFolder, OverwriteExisting  
Else

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> set objWShell=wScript.createObject("WScript.Shell")
>> WScript.Echo objWShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%\mainfolder\subfolder\netcfg.ini")
>>
C:\Program Files\mainfolder\subfolder\netcfg.ini
>>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a bit new to vbs so how do i implement this into my script?
I implemented it but that does nothing the file is not beeing overwritten.